# Sound card not recognized (Dummy output) in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, intel, lts

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in a laptop, and i can't get the speakers or headphones to work. I only get Dummy output for output devices, at the beggining my system wasn't able to recognize any audio device, then i tried different solutions i found in the internet, so i get now the device listed, but still i only get the Dummy output. Here are some outputs i get:

```
diego@diego-NBLB-WAX9N:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xb121c000 irq 149
diego@diego-NBLB-WAX9N:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS [8086:02c8]
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS [152d:1260]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
diego@diego-NBLB-WAX9N:~$ aplay -l
**** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware ****
tarjeta 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
diego@diego-NBLB-WAX9N:~$ pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb121c000 irq 149"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "02c8"
        device.product.name = "Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Audio Interno"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Salida Digital Stereo (HDMI) (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Salida Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Salida Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Salida Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Salida Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Salida Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Salida Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Salida Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Salida Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Apagado (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

I looked many solutions but none worked.

EDIT:
Here i add the suggested command output.

```
diego@diego-NBLB-WAX9N:~$ journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"
sep 26 12:23:56 diego-NBLB-WAX9N kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
sep 26 12:23:56 diego-NBLB-WAX9N kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
sep 26 12:23:56 diego-NBLB-WAX9N kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
sep 26 12:23:56 diego-NBLB-WAX9N kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
sep 26 12:23:56 diego-NBLB-WAX9N kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
sep 26 12:23:56 diego-NBLB-WAX9N kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
```

Comment: Add `journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"` output